# How do I minimize storage impact (bytes) of audit columns in database tables?

Tags: sql-server, database, azure, data-modeling

I'm a senior database developer who has always practiced creating four auditing columns on most database tables, if not all, as follows:

- DATE_INSERTED
- USER_INSERTED
- DATE_UPDATED
- USER_UPDATED

The reasons I wish to capture this information is NOT to comply with some external auditing requirements like Sarbanes Oxley.  It's simply for troubleshooting purposes when Development is asked to investigate some data scenario in the database, and knowing who originally inserted some record and when, as well as who last updated it and when, strongly aids in the troubleshooting effort.  Needing to store every version/state of that record that ever existed is probably overkill, but might be useful in some cases.

I'm new to both Azure SQL Database (essentially SQL Server) and its memory-optimized tables (in-memory tables), which I'm planning to implement.  The amount of bytes you can store in memory database-wide is limited, so I'm being very conscious of limiting the number of bytes I put into memory, especially for large tables.  Well, these four auditing columns will eat up a significant number of in-memory bytes if I add them to large in-memory tables, and I'd love to avoid that.  These audit columns will never be queried or displayed in app code or reports, but they will be likely be populated by a combination of column default values, triggers and app code.

My question is whether there's a good data modeling strategy to keep these four columns out of memory, while keeping the remainder of the table in memory?  The worst-case scenario seems like creating your main in-memory table, and then create a separate on-disk table with the 4 audit columns and a UNIQUE FOREIGN KEY column pointing to the in-memory table (thereby creating a 1-to-1 FK instead of 1-to-many).  But I was hoping there was a more elegant approach to accomplish this in-memory/on-disk split, perhaps leveraging some SQL Server feature I haven't been able to find.  As a bonus, it'd be nice if the main table and the audit columns appear as a single table to SQL without having to implement a database view.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: If you were unaware Azure has auditing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-auditing

Comment: Are you sure you need them in the first place? SQL Server has change tracking since 2005 and temporal tables since 2016. Temporal tables can be used to store and retrieve historical values *without* extra code

Comment: *Why* do you want the audit columns? What *actual* need are you trying to address? As for memory limits - there's no reason to store history in memory. There may not be any reason to use *in-memory* tables either, unless there are a **lot** of concurrent modifications.

Comment: Finally, how large is the table? Why not use eg columnstore indexes? They offer both in-memory acceleration and compression. You can also create columnstore indexes on top of in-memory tables. Or you can use compression on the historical table

Comment: Agree withe the comment above to use the temporal tables instead (if you really need this). Also if you can afford the table wide auditing instead of the row level extended events might be better choice for you here.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos if they use columnstore for these audit tables, you can take it further to divide the date and time columns for even more compression.

Comment: Great input everyone.  Much appreciated.  I've updated the second paragraph of my original post with the reason I wish to add the audit columns.  Sorry for omitting that the first time around.

I'll research temporal tables and columnstore indices, as they sound promising.  I love the comment about separating the DATE and TIME fields for better compression.

I don't thing the Azure auditing meets my needs, as I need record-level auditing, and I *believe* that's database-level auditing, though I could be wrong.

Comment: So I've created a temporal table to play around with.  I now realize that it's a great tool to know what a table's data looked like at a specific moment in time, but that's not my use case.  I can jump thru a few hoops to get the timestamps I'm looking for, but it doesn't store which database user performed the DML action, though, as far as I can tell.  Now onto researching columnstore indices...